# Rails/Devise - sign_out not working in Safari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using the Devise gem for user authentication in my Rails app.  I am finding that the `sign_out` helper method is not working in Safari, both desktop and mobile - it works just fine in Chrome, etc.

I am trying to force a signed in user to sign out when they hit a particular controller action:

```
def new
    if user_signed_in?
        sign_out
    end
end
```

But this has no effect.  The `user_signed_in?` and `destroy_user_session_path` functionality work ok in the views, as in

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
<% end %>
```

but calling `sign_out` from the controller is a no-go.

Has anyone experienced these kinds of cross-browser issues with Devise, and is there a way that I can fix this or otherwise achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Go in config/application.rb and set `serve_static_assets` by `true`

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Or

Add to routes.rb

```
match '/logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :via => [:delete]
```

Then, your link for sign out should be like this

```
<%= link_to 'Sign Out', logout_path %>
```

If it doesn't work, try overriding the Devise::SessionsController like this:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
 def log_out
  user = current_user
  sign_out user
 end
end
```

Comment: This should not be used in production, so is likely not a valid solution.

Comment: @BorisBresciani Sorry man, this doesn't seem to be working... the `if user signed_in?` block even works just fine in a different controller... why would it be flopping in just this one instance?